# What does "FILE *fp, *fopen();" do?

Tags: c, unix

On page 182 of [The UNIX Programming environment](https://cs.uwec.edu/~buipj/teaching/cs.388.s14/static/pdf/upe.pdf) the code for `efopen` is listed as follows:

```
FILE *efopen(file, mode)    /* fopen file, die if can't */
    char *file, *mode;
{
    FILE *fp, *fopen();
    extern char *progname;

    if ((fp = fopen(file, mode)) != NULL)
        return fp;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open file %s mode %s\n",
        progname, file, mode);
    exit(1);
}
```

What does the line `FILE *fp, *fopen();` do?

My reading is that it declares a variable `fp` which is a pointer to a `FILE` and a function `fopen` which returns a pointer to a `FILE`.

If so: Why is `fopen` forward declared within the function body? How come we don't declare its arguments?

Comment: The book (which is in many ways excellent) was written in 1984, five years before the first C standard.  Funnily enough, it doesn't use features found only in standard C, such as function prototypes.  All the C is now similarly antiquated — in the computing world, few books withstand the changes of 30+ years completely unscathed.  You will need to understand pre-standard (K&R 1st Edition) C to make good use of it.  There are a few places where it is hard to reconcile the code with modern C — but not many.

Comment: If you get really stuck on some conversion of code from the book, contact me by email — see my profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It creates a local variable named `fp` (of type `FILE *`), and forward declares [an external function named `fopen` (with a signature of `FILE *fopen()`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html).

The lack of parameters in the `fopen` function declaration in C doesn't mean the function takes zero parameters (that function signature would be `FILE *fopen(void)`). Instead, the lack of parameters means the function has unspecified parameters (unspecified in quantity and unspecified in type).

This is a really old form of C that would be more idiomatically written in modern C as:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen() and fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit()
#include <string.h>  // strerror()
#include <errno.h>   // errno

extern char *progname;

FILE *efopen(const char *file, const char *mode) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, mode);
    if (fp) return fp;

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open file %s in mode %s: %s\n",
            progname, file, mode, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I have literally never seen a C codebase in which the open curly brace of a function definition went at the end of the line like you're doing it.  JavaScript, yes, C, never.  Where did you pick that up?

Comment: @zwol: [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html). And perhaps reinforced by writing [Objective-C](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/cd5e62a5597ea7a31dccef089317abb3a661c154/runtime/NSObject.mm#L1877) (which is admittedly a different language, but some code bases put the brace on the same line as the method's selector, and for consistency do the same with plain C functions in an Objective-C file; Apple's code (which I linked to) doesn't demonstrate that but some other code bases do).